# vb referencing a column via a variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, vbscript, ms-access-2003

I am trying to update an Access database with a vb script by putting a soccer scoreline into a column dependent on when a goal is scored.

So I have a table, tblScoreLinesByMinute, with columns

```
matchID 1 2 3 4.... 89 90
```

which in my script I have set

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblScoreLinesByMinute", dbOpenTable)
```

Let us say there was a goal scored by the home team in the 3rd minute
I have captured this with a variable `numTime = 3` and created a variable `strScoreline = 10`.
I wish to update the table something like

```
rst![numTime] = strScoreline
```

but if I try this or `CStr(numTime)` I get a runtime error "Item not found in this collection". A hard coded

`rst![3] = strScoreline`  does work

I am also keen to set the other columns to the relevant scoreline. Let us say that the away team equalized in the 88th minute. What I am after is having the row for this particular match showing a scoreline for columns 1,2 of '00', columns 3 to 87 inc '10' and columns 88-90 '11'

I could use mssql as well if there is a simpler method for that

Comment: This data structure is really bad. It is completely denormalized and each of your records with many columns, most of them blank, should be a row in a separate table (only when there's a value).

Comment: Agreed. This was a stage in attempting to answer my question on predicting game outcomes in soccer. I was subsequently helped via my question on populating one sql table with values from another if you want to read furhter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the first part of your question correctly, I think you should try this:

```
rst.Fields(numTime) = strScoreline
```

I have no clue about the second part of your question.

**Edit**: Your comment made me think your numTime text values were being interpreted as numbers rather than string values by rst.Fields.  However, that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Opening a recordset based on the same table and field names, this code throws an error ("Item not found in this collection"):

```
numTime = "0"
Debug.Print rst.Fields(numTime)
```

But this code prints the value of the column named "2":

```
numTime = "2"
Debug.Print rst.Fields(numTime)
```

So I still don't understand why it's not working for you.  But I've never used numbers as column names; it just seems wrong to me.  I would be more surprised if you renamed your columns as MatchID, f1, f2, f3 and this approach still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you understood right. Thanks for answering the first part

Comment: Actually it appears as this will put my variable into the column with an index of numTime,   not the column named numTime - but in my situation this is easily taken account of. I can then use a for loop to also write that strScoreline to all columns with a higher index number viz time of game . Once that has been done, the same process is done for any other goal scored in the game overwriting as required such that when I loop to the next number I have the correct scoreline for each minute of the game entered